# Google Play in-app purchase app icon not shown

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, google-play-console

I'm currently finishing an Android app and have just realized that the in-app purchase dialog does not show the app's icon. For reference, we are using Flutter v2 with the flutter_launcher_icons packages.

[image]

Is there a way to specify an icon per subscription or is this maybe related to the fact that the app is not yet approved?

Comment: You need to send it for close beta review at least; after that, the icons will show.